# Change default behavior of Approvals and checks in Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an environment-dependent 'Approvals and checks' Azure functions step before my deployment should start.
Since this step times out after a while (which is desirable), I´d like to inform the dev team to take a look at it.
However, once the approval times out, every subsequent step in my pipeline gets skipped immediately.

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this doc: [Approvals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#approvals)

> If all required approvals are not complete within the Timeout specified for the approval and all other checks succeed, the stage is marked skipped.

This is an expected behavior in Pipeline Environment.

I am afraid that there is no such method can change the default behavior now.

I suggest you can increase the **Timeout** to make sure you have enough time to inform the dev team.

For example:

[image]

On the other hand, you can also create a [Suggestion Ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to report the feature requirement.

Comment: thx for your answer. I will do, though do you have another idea how to model the behavior of 1. have an automated approval step and 2. only send out a mail (or whatever) once this tasks times out?

Comment: I agree with Point 2. For point 1 , Probably not a good idea for automatic approval, it skips the review process and can cause some unexpected issue.  I suggest that it can automatically send an email to the required approvers when the approval request is generated, and send the email again before the set time is reached

Comment: Agree, it seems like a doable workaround, though, Is there a way to get the *Control Options* settings from within a function? They don´t seem to exist in the env...

Comment: Yes. Apparently env doesn't support this for now. Maybe function can work as workaround. You can use Rest API to get the status of the approval: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1 . But it will be more complicated. Hopefully this feature can be added directly to env via the suggestion ticket. If you create the suggestion ticket, you can share here. I can help you vote it.